# Copy Docker network from one host to another

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm trying to migrate docker containers from one host to another and I've managed to move the containers, but they all complain that the network is missing:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network service_backend not found.
```

How do I copy that network over to the new host?

The config for the containers contains:

```
--network "service_backend"
```

And the `docker network inspect service_backend` looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "service_backend",
        "Id": "3a950dfe6c80bbac958d8965cbe2e94febd742d5356dcb0c790bf1e78a9bb2ca",
        "Created": "2018-03-10T03:26:26.482281374Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "176cd874ca33599e99bdd4733d1e52ae347d37601d59b822cf444f5bbba38e36": {
                "Name": "service_1",
                "EndpointID": "415f640791e7a4e334205343f397c3bafe61ad3762599cc2d009c264d95c424c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a61e8acb70912af4401831158e2bcd46b39be1c5acbf5beeb8a847bbf80eb759": {
                "Name": "service_nginx_1",
                "EndpointID": "c6438e1745c5823f78d172cb47f45e59275466880a9e5bd8be1d420a7467e5da",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "backend",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "service"
        }
    }
]
```

How might I back that up and move it over?

Comment: "Copy networks" doesn't really make sense.  You'd typically use `docker network create` or `docker-compose up` to create the network the same way you did on the original system.  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating a setup that doesn't work?  How are you creating the containers?

Comment: The containers I'm moving reference the network config being used by name.  I can print out the network config but is there no way to migrate it over?

Comment: The `docker network inspect` output you have shows Compose labels.  Can you copy the original `docker-compose.yml` to the target system and just run `docker-compose up` there?

Comment: Unfortunately the original compose file is long gone, all I have are the running containers.